# Backbone.js collection.remove documentation explanation

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Can someone please clearly explain how to interpret the documentation for the `collection.remove()` method in backbone.js as seen here:

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-remove

The docs show `collection.remove(models, [options])`, but I don't understand what this means for the actual usage of the function.  What does `options` represent here?  I'm confused because the callback also has an options argument as seen here:

http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog

The callback docs say:

"remove" (model, collection, options) — when a model is removed from a collection.

This means if I call `collection.remove(model)` somewhere in my code, my callbacks will be passed the collection, the model, and an options parameter.  Is this options parameter the same one that can optionally be passed in on the remove call itself.  If so, what are these options supposed to be used for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would read the links that you posted, you will see this

"Generally speaking, when calling a function that emits an event (model.set, collection.add, and so on...), if you'd like to prevent the event from being triggered, **you may pass {silent: true} as an option**. Note that this is rarely, perhaps even never, a good idea. **Passing through a specific flag in the options for your event callback to look at**, and choose to ignore, will usually work out better."

So you can use the `options` to prevent the remove event from firing. You can also use it (as mentioned in the last sentence) to pass option values to the callback. So yes, anything you pass in as options to the `remove` function will be passed through as the options to the `remove` event.